# how can I make a .pdf file using php?

Tags: php, pdf

i have this letter where in some parts will be filled-up by the user. like this:

> I am `<input name="age" type="text">` years old.

is it possible to save the letter into a .pdf file?

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624578/dynamically-insert-content-into-pdf-files-with-php and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an article that describes the process [here](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Create-Pdf-Php_t4972.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) from the [Zend_Framework](http://framework.zend.com). The good thing about Zend_Framework is that you can add just the parts of it you need. The modules seldom have dependency on each other.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org)

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: We're using FPDF within our group.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php) suggests using Prince XML.